# Insert rows using mysqldump and count the rows

Tags: shell, mysql

Can we count the rows when we `insert rows` using `mysqldump`?
I am doing script for moving large data.I have making backup table and from than `mysqldump` backup table moving rows to another database table.
How will be count the rows when,the Insert operation running for `mysqldump` and again when moving.?
help me! thanx.

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --lock-all-tables --no-create-db 
--no-create-info --extended-insert --password=XXX -u XXX 
--dump-date yyy > yyy_dataOnly.sql
```

like this can we used --count rows... ?

Comment: you want to count the rows after the mysql dump ??

Comment: Yes! or can we count when we inserting rows...?

Comment: count function  where? I want it throught the script

Comment: @AvinashBabu What happen pls help? If you no something about this.